# strip symbols with regex and then put them all back

Tags: python, regex, string, list

I am trying to strip the punctuation on a string with regex, then do some analysis and then put the punctuation back where it was after the analysis. I have removed it but i'm not sure how to place it back after i make the changes?

```
import re
s = "I want to remove all the punctuation, and then put it, back where it was."
s = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]','',s)

lst = s.split()
# now i  change the list
# how to put the symbols back after i change the list?
```

Comment: Simply add a variable to hold original string. `original = s`.

Comment: Note that `str` is immutable in `python`. So `s = re.sub(...)` part actually doesn't affect original `str` object. It just reassigns `s`.

Comment: Please try [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60754456/3832970).

Comment: You are supposed to accept an answer that helped you. Please feel free to press the green tick on the left of an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`str` is immutable object in python.

```
s = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]','',s)
```

part does just reassign `s`.
So you can preserve original string with another name(variable).

```py
import re

original_s = "I want to remove all the punctuation, and then put it, back where it was."
s = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]', '', original_s)

lst = s.split()

# now i  change the list
# how to put the symbols back after i change the list?

print(lst)
print(s)
print(original_s)
```

output:

```
['I', 'want', 'to', 'remove', 'all', 'the', 'punctuation', 'and', 'then', 'put', 'it', 'back', 'where', 'it', 'was']
I want to remove all the punctuation and then put it back where it was
I want to remove all the punctuation, and then put it, back where it was.
```

---

Appended

> What i want though is after i change the lst, to get all the symbols back from the original_s and place them back on the lst, so that i can turn it into a string again with both the changes and the initial symbols.

You have two simple options:

1. using `str.replace`. not to convert it to string in the first place.
2. convert including punctuations.

---

#### solution 1. using `str.replace`

```py
text = "PET scan is an imaging test that allows your doctor to check for diseases in your body."

acronym_dict = {
    'PET': 'Positron emission tomography'
}

for acronym, word in acronym_dict.items():
    text = text.replace(acronym, word)

print(text)
```

output:

```
Positron emission tomography scan is an imaging test that allows your doctor to check for diseases in your body.
```

---

#### solution 2. `lst` with punctuations

```py
import re

text = "PET scan is an imaging test that allows your doctor to check for diseases in your body."

acronym_dict = {
    'PET': 'Positron emission tomography'
}

lst = re.split(r'\b', text)
print(lst)

result = ''.join(
    acronym_dict.get(word, word)
    for word in lst
)

print(result)
```

output

```
['', 'PET', ' ', 'scan', ' ', 'is', ' ', 'an', ' ', 'imaging', ' ', 'test', ' ', 'that', ' ', 'allows', ' ', 'your', ' ', 'doctor', ' ', 'to', ' ', 'check', ' ', 'for', ' ', 'diseases', ' ', 'in', ' ', 'your', ' ', 'body', '.']
Positron emission tomography scan is an imaging test that allows your doctor to check for diseases in your body.
```

Comment: Thank you. What i want though is after i change the lst, to get all the symbols back from the original_s and place them back on the lst, so that i can turn it into a string again with both the changes and the initial symbols.

Comment: Can you explain details about a range of changes? For example, order, word, and so on.

Comment: So i have some string with some acronym ( str = '' PET scan is an imaging test that allows your doctor to check for diseases in your body.'') and i want to replace the acronyms with their full form. So the string above will turn to '' Positron emission tomography scan is an imaging test that allows your doctor to check for diseases in your body.''

Answer (score 0):

You can create a temporary string instead and try this below:

```
    input_string = "I want to remove all the punctuation, and then put it, back where it was."
    s = input_string
    s = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]', '', s)

    lst = s.split()

    print(input_string)
```

Answer (score 0):

You just want to make sure that you are not modifying the original string, which is `s`. To make this possible, assign the `re.sub` result to a new variable:

```
modified_s = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]','',s)
```

This does not modify the original `s`.
You can do all your analysis on `modified_s` and when you want the original, get it from `s`.

```
import re

s = "I want to remove all the punctuation, and then put it, back where it was."
modified_s = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]','',s)  # new object

lst = modified_s.split()              # perform operations on the new object.

print(s)                              # this is still the original object.
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `re.sub` with a pattern that will match and capture either the  punctuation chunks, or the non-punctuation chunks and pass the match object to a callable where you may perform any changes to the non-punctuation strings while simply returning the punctuation texts unchanged:

```
import re
def repl(m):
    if m.group(1):
        return m.group(1).upper()
    else:
        return m.group()

s = "I want to remove all the punctuation, and then put it, back where it was."
s = re.sub(r'([\w\s]+)|[^\w\s]+', repl, s)
print(s) # => I WANT TO REMOVE ALL THE PUNCTUATION, AND THEN PUT IT, BACK WHERE IT WAS.
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/q5YxVP) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WzjDa3/2).